# How do I display a dropdown list on clicking a radio button?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a task where I have to display seperate dropdown lists for each option in radio buttons. When I select a radio button (not selecting a radio button and then clicking on 'submit'. Just selecting(clicking on) a radio button), the corresponding dropdown list should be displayed in the side.

Comment: With the onchange event.

Answer (score 1):

You want to listen to the on 'change' event, this is an example with jquery:

```
 $('select').hide();

 $('input').on('change', function(){
      $('select').show();
 })
```

I've dropped a working example into jsbin: https://jsbin.com/xohecizina/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

I made an example for you [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mbcgjbcx/).

The example is basically the following steps:

1. Mark up your HTML

   ```
   <label>Radio 1</label>
   <input type="radio" name="group" value="1" checked />
   <label>Radio 2</label>
   <input type="radio" name="group" value="2" />
   <label>Radio 3</label>
   <input type="radio" name="group" value="3" />

   <div>
     <select id="drop1">
       <option>DropDown 1</option>
     </select>
     <select id="drop2" class="no-display">
       <option>DropDown 2</option>
     </select>
     <select id="drop3" class="no-display">
       <option>DropDown 3</option>
     </select>
   </div>
   ```
2. Add CSS

   ```
   .no-display {display: none;}
   ```
3. Add event listeners to the radio buttons that call your drop-down selecting function

   ```
   var radio_buttons = document.getElementsByName("group");

   for (var i = 0; i < radio_buttons.length; i++) {
       radio_buttons[i].addEventListener("change", setDropDown);
   }

   function setDropDown() {
       setDropDownsForNoDisplay();
       if (this.checked) {
           setDropDownForDisplay(this.value);        
       }
   }
   ```
4. Add helper functions that the drop-down selecting function uses

   ```
   var dropdowns = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
   function setDropDownsForNoDisplay() {
       for (var i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
           dropdowns[i].classList.add("no-display");
       }
   }

   function setDropDownForDisplay(x) {
       if (x === "1") {
           document.getElementById("drop1").classList.remove("no-display");
       } else if (x === "2") {
           document.getElementById("drop2").classList.remove("no-display");
       } else if (x === "3") {
           document.getElementById("drop3").classList.remove("no-display");
       }
   }
   ```

You could also use events ("onclick", "onchange") directly in the radio button markup instead of adding event listeners, but I prefer keeping my events separated from the markup.